# Getting resource 404 not available tomcat

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to develop a HelloWorld example in Spring MVC, I already know Java but I'm new in spring, I'm following this tutorialspoint tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm
I had some problems but in one moment it was Ok and working, then I moved on to the next tutorial and then it's not longer working, even if I delete all the new files and I can't find the reason.
(I just pointed the change of tutorials in case this is the reason, but maybe this is not relevant).

-Here is my web.xml

```
<web-app id = "WebApp_ID" version = "2.4"
xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

-HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package = "com.tutorialspoint" />

<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

-HelloController.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

-hello.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType = "text/html; charset = UTF-8" %>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h2>${message}</h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

And my directories
[Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k194X.png)

To deploy it in Tomcat I just do right click on the project in Eclipse > export > WAR file, and save it in webapps folder in Tomcat, there I have Jenkins war too and Jenkins works ok, I can see the Tomcat Homepage ok also, so I think it's not a Tomcat problem but I'm open to suggestions.

Then I go to `localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello` and I get the error.
I've searched for some days and any solution I've found have worked for me.

**Edit 1**

My HelloWeb-servlet.xml after Amit K Bist reply

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd 
springframework.org/schema/mvc 
springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package = "com.tutorialspoint" />

<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

I got error

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.
- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 
 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

at line 12

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not enabled annotation in your HelloWeb-servlet.xml, please add below code

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

before

```
<context:component-scan base-package = "com.tutorialspoint" />
```

Comment: I missed it but You need to add <mvc:annotation-driven /> in your HelloWeb-servlet.xml and your bean configuration needs to refer/updated to xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"

Comment: I just edited the question to reply to your answer, I still have an error.

Comment: `'xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd"` this is the correct format, stackoverflow converted  previous one to the link and removed `http://www.` from the code

Comment: I edited it and I don't longer have the error, but it's still not working

Comment: I created a Project using same tutorial which you are referring to and its working fine for me. I think you changed a few items when you moved to the next tutorial, so its better to clean everything from webapp/installedapp folder in tomcat and clean all the classes folder, and try it again.

Comment: I just create a new project and perform the first tutorial again, this is working ok now, I'm gonna move on to the next very carefully and I hope everything it's ok, if I find a mistake I'll ask you again but however I'll mark the answer. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I just perform the second one and everything is ok now, but in .jsp I have an error "The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build 
 Path", I had that error later so I did some things to fix it, now I just ignored the error and the project works perfectly, I think this was the tricky, bit I think is quite weird that error, however, Thank you very much for your help @Amit K Bist